# Custom naming of Aeroo report filename in Odoo

Tags: filenames, odoo, aeroolib

is there any way to get the report output from Aeroo named with a custom naming pattern?
I.e., for the invoice: [year]_[invoice number]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Raffaele, I'd recommend taking a look [here](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/8.0/report_custom_filename) and to [this forum post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/8-0-how-can-i-create-a-custom-report-filename-for-odoo-eg-so039-2015-04-25-pdf-84454).

You'll need to use some basic `python` logic in the `report_custom_filename` module to create the file name you need according to your requirements.

Using the following example I can create output for a filename for *Sales Order/Quotation*:

```
${(object.name or '').replace('/','_')}_${object.state == 'draft' and 'draft' or '' +'.xls'}
```

That looks like this:

`SO039_.xls`

You can add another field from the *document/report* you're printing out by adding another section, for example:

```
${(object.client_order_ref or '').replace('/','_')}_
```

this will add the field `client_order_ref` in front of the document name like this:

```
[Here's your client order reference]_SO039.xls
```

Have a look at what fields are available in the model you're trying to get this information from (eg. in my case `sale.order`) and I think you'll find roughly what you need there.

I have still not figured out how to add a date/timestamp like you are requesting (eg. Year), however someone else may be able to offer some advice on this.

Comment: Date/ Timestamp ${format_tz(object.write_date, tz='UTC', format='%d/%m/%Y')}  Found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146954/formatting-date-in-odoo-email-template by My Phillip Stack