# Formatting date in odoo email template

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In odoo 9 i need to format the date_invoice in %d/%m/%Y inside email template:

```
Invoice date: ${object.date_invoice}
```

The code above return 2017-03-31 but it is in wrong locale.

How i can format to get 31/03/2017 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve using alternative different way.

**${ object.date_invoice and object.date_invoice.split('-')[1] + '/' + object.date_invoice.split('-')[2] + '/' + object.date_invoice.split('-')[0] or ''}**

Comment: It's working fine except when the value is null, i get an error

Answer (score 3):

Qweb has a `format_tz()` function here is an example

${format_tz(object.write_date, tz='UTC', format='%d/%m/%Y')}

Now I think this function may only work on a datetime but you could probably add a new field to the model which is calculated from the date field you have and call it a day.

You can find a usage here `event/data/email_template_data.xml`

Comment: Where i can find event/data/email_template_data.xml?

Comment: Should be in your addons directory.

Comment: Although the suggestion by Empiro may be a quicker solution to be honest.

Comment: Sure, ugly but quicker ;)

Comment: Not everything has to be beautiful. And I think this qualifies. Sometimes things dont have to be right. Just not wrong.

Comment: Thank you Philip, by far the best to format dates in email template